# How can you be more specific in a DLL reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Getting this error:

```
Parser Error Message: The type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage' is
ambiguous: it could come from assembly
'\\vmware-host\shared folders\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClientApp\ClientApp\bin\
      Boilerplate.Web.Mvc5.Sample.DLL'
or from assembly
'\\vmware-host\shared folders\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClientApp\ClientApp\bin\
     System.Web.Mvc.DLL'.
Please specify the assembly explicitly in the type name.
```

From this code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

How can you be more specific in a DLL reference?

FYI, my controller is an MVC 5 controller with an action that looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var view = new WebFormView(this.ControllerContext, "~/Views/Conduces/Index.aspx");

        return View(view);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the assembly name as part of the `Inherits` property value:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage,System.Web.Mvc" %>
```

Note the two-part name with the type name first, followed by the assembly name.